# Counting distributions of $52$ cards among $4$ players without distinguishing suits

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Imagine a card deck with no suits (no spades, hearts etc.). So there are 4 identical aces, 4 identical 2's and so on.

In how many ways can you distribute these cards to 4 players with each player getting 13 cards?

What if the players are indistinguishable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a hard problem, but at least for the first case I can give an exact solution. As dhrab indicated, a distribution is determined (up to the level at which you chose to want to distinguish them) by indicating for every value$~v$ and every player$~p$ how many instances of$~v$ are held by$~p$, giving a $13\times 4$ matrix of natural numbers with row sums $(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)$ and column sums $(13,13,13,13)$. Counting such matrices has an application in the representation theory of the symmetric group: that number is the scalar product between the representations of the symmetric group $S_{52}$ induced from the trivial representations of the respective Young subgroups $S_{13}^4$ and $S_4^{13}$. Those are not so easy to compute, but a redeeming feature is that that former only has irreducible factors parametrised by partitions $\lambda$ of $52$ with at most $4$ nonzero parts; these are only $1285$ of the $281589$ irreducible representations. This allows doing the computation using the corresponding polynomial representation theory of $GL(4,\Bbb C)$, which is equivalent as far as partitions with at most $4$ parts is concerned, but where other partitions give no irreducible representations.

So what I did, using our computer program [LiE](http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/), is compute for type $A_3$ (which actually gives representations of $SL(4,\Bbb C)$, and can be seen to be good enough) the decomposition of the $4$-th tensor power of the representation with highest weight $[13,0,0]$ and the $13$-th tensor power of the representation with highest weight $[4,0,0]$, and compute the scalar product (sum of products of matching coefficients) of the resulting polynomials. The answer is
$\color{red}{151\,309\,409\,779\,981\,285}$.

An alternative take on this method is that matrices of the given type correspond through the [RSK corrrespondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted%E2%80%93Knuth_correspondence) to pairs of equal shape semistandard Young tableaux of size $52$, the first with entries $1,2,3,4$ each occurring $13$ times, and the second with entries $1,2,\ldots,13$ each occurring $4$ times. The polynomials describing the distributions of such tableaux (how many of each shape) can be computed using the [Littlewood-Richardson rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%E2%80%93Richardson_rule). The tableaux of the latter type are much more numerous and can involve many more shapes, but we need only consider those shapes that also occur for the first type, thus we may use a truncating version of the Littlewood-Richardson rule (just drop all terms involving partitions with more than $4$ parts; they never later contribute to partitions that would not also be dropped).

Here is (most of) the distribution of tableaux with weight $(13,13,13,13)$:

```
   1X[13,13,13,13] +  3X[14,13,13,12] +  2X[14,14,12,12] +
   3X[14,14,13,11] +  1X[14,14,14,10] +  3X[15,13,12,12] +
   6X[15,13,13,11] +  7X[15,14,12,11] +  8X[15,14,13,10] +
   3X[15,14,14, 9] +  3X[15,15,11,11] +  6X[15,15,12,10] +
   6X[15,15,13, 9] +  3X[15,15,14, 8] +  1X[15,15,15, 7] +
   1X[16,12,12,12] +  8X[16,13,12,11] + 10X[16,13,13,10] +
   6X[16,14,11,11] + 15X[16,14,12,10] + 15X[16,14,13, 9] +
   6X[16,14,14, 8] + 11X[16,15,11,10] + 16X[16,15,12, 9] +
  15X[16,15,13, 8] +  8X[16,15,14, 7] +  3X[16,15,15, 6] +
   4X[16,16,10,10] +  9X[16,16,11, 9] + 11X[16,16,12, 8] +
  10X[16,16,13, 7] +  6X[16,16,14, 6] +  3X[16,16,15, 5] +
   1X[16,16,16, 4] +  3X[17,12,12,11] +  6X[17,13,11,11] +
  15X[17,13,12,10] + 15X[17,13,13, 9] + 16X[17,14,11,10] +
  26X[17,14,12, 9] + 24X[17,14,13, 8] + 10X[17,14,14, 7] +
   9X[17,15,10,10] + 24X[17,15,11, 9] + 30X[17,15,12, 8] +
  27X[17,15,13, 7] + 15X[17,15,14, 6] +  6X[17,15,15, 5] +
  15X[17,16,10, 9] + 24X[17,16,11, 8] + 27X[17,16,12, 7] +
  24X[17,16,13, 6] + 15X[17,16,14, 5] +  8X[17,16,15, 4] +
   3X[17,16,16, 3] +  5X[17,17, 9, 9] + 12X[17,17,10, 8] +
  16X[17,17,11, 7] + 17X[17,17,12, 6] + 15X[17,17,13, 5] +
  10X[17,17,14, 4] +  6X[17,17,15, 3] +  3X[17,17,16, 2] +
   1X[17,17,17, 1] +  3X[18,12,11,11] +  6X[18,12,12,10] +
  15X[18,13,11,10] + 24X[18,13,12, 9] + 21X[18,13,13, 8] +
  11X[18,14,10,10] + 30X[18,14,11, 9] + 40X[18,14,12, 8] +
  35X[18,14,13, 7] + 15X[18,14,14, 6] + 24X[18,15,10, 9] +
  42X[18,15,11, 8] + 48X[18,15,12, 7] + 42X[18,15,13, 6] +
  24X[18,15,14, 5] + 10X[18,15,15, 4] + 12X[18,16, 9, 9] +
  33X[18,16,10, 8] + 45X[18,16,11, 7] + 48X[18,16,12, 6] +
  42X[18,16,13, 5] + 27X[18,16,14, 4] + 15X[18,16,15, 3] +
   6X[18,16,16, 2] + 19X[18,17, 9, 8] + 32X[18,17,10, 7] +
  39X[18,17,11, 6] + 40X[18,17,12, 5] + 35X[18,17,13, 4] +
  24X[18,17,14, 3] + 15X[18,17,15, 2] +  8X[18,17,16, 1] +
   3X[18,17,17, 0] +  6X[18,18, 8, 8] + 15X[18,18, 9, 7] +
  21X[18,18,10, 6] + 24X[18,18,11, 5] + 24X[18,18,12, 4] +
  21X[18,18,13, 3] + 15X[18,18,14, 2] + 10X[18,18,15, 1] +
   6X[18,18,16, 0] +  1X[19,11,11,11] +  8X[19,12,11,10] +
  10X[19,12,12, 9] + 10X[19,13,10,10] + 27X[19,13,11, 9] +
  35X[19,13,12, 8] + 28X[19,13,13, 7] + 27X[19,14,10, 9] +
  48X[19,14,11, 8] + 57X[19,14,12, 7] + 48X[19,14,13, 6] +
  21X[19,14,14, 5] + 16X[19,15, 9, 9] + 45X[19,15,10, 8] +
  65X[19,15,11, 7] + 70X[19,15,12, 6] + 60X[19,15,13, 5] +
  35X[19,15,14, 4] + 15X[19,15,15, 3] + 32X[19,16, 9, 8] +
  58X[19,16,10, 7] + 72X[19,16,11, 6] + 74X[19,16,12, 5] +
  64X[19,16,13, 4] + 42X[19,16,14, 3] + 24X[19,16,15, 2] +
  10X[19,16,16, 1] + 15X[19,17, 8, 8] + 42X[19,17, 9, 7] +
  60X[19,17,10, 6] + 69X[19,17,11, 5] + 69X[19,17,12, 4] +
  60X[19,17,13, 3] + 42X[19,17,14, 2] + 27X[19,17,15, 1] +
  15X[19,17,16, 0] + 23X[19,18, 8, 7] + 40X[19,18, 9, 6] +
  51X[19,18,10, 5] + 56X[19,18,11, 4] + 55X[19,18,12, 3] +
  48X[19,18,13, 2] + 35X[19,18,14, 1] + 24X[19,18,15, 0] +
   7X[19,19, 7, 7] + 18X[19,19, 8, 6] + 26X[19,19, 9, 5] +
  31X[19,19,10, 4] + 33X[19,19,11, 3] + 32X[19,19,12, 2] +
  28X[19,19,13, 1] + 21X[19,19,14, 0] +  3X[20,11,11,10] +
   6X[20,12,10,10] + 15X[20,12,11, 9] + 15X[20,12,12, 8] +
  24X[20,13,10, 9] + 42X[20,13,11, 8] + 48X[20,13,12, 7] +
  36X[20,13,13, 6] + 17X[20,14, 9, 9] + 48X[20,14,10, 8] +
  70X[20,14,11, 7] + 77X[20,14,12, 6] + 63X[20,14,13, 5] +
  28X[20,14,14, 4] + 39X[20,15, 9, 8] + 72X[20,15,10, 7] +
  93X[20,15,11, 6] + 96X[20,15,12, 5] + 81X[20,15,13, 4] +
  48X[20,15,14, 3] + 21X[20,15,15, 2] + 21X[20,16, 8, 8] +
  60X[20,16, 9, 7] + 90X[20,16,10, 6] +105X[20,16,11, 5] +
 105X[20,16,12, 4] + 90X[20,16,13, 3] + 60X[20,16,14, 2] +
  35X[20,16,15, 1] + 15X[20,16,16, 0] + 40X[20,17, 8, 7] +
  74X[20,17, 9, 6] + 96X[20,17,10, 5] +106X[20,17,11, 4] +
 104X[20,17,12, 3] + 90X[20,17,13, 2] + 64X[20,17,14, 1] +
  42X[20,17,15, 0] + 18X[20,18, 7, 7] + 51X[20,18, 8, 6] +
  75X[20,18, 9, 5] + 90X[20,18,10, 4] + 96X[20,18,11, 3] +
  93X[20,18,12, 2] + 81X[20,18,13, 1] + 60X[20,18,14, 0] +
  27X[20,19, 7, 6] + 48X[20,19, 8, 5] + 63X[20,19, 9, 4] +
  72X[20,19,10, 3] + 75X[20,19,11, 2] + 72X[20,19,12, 1] +
  63X[20,19,13, 0] +  8X[20,20, 6, 6] + 21X[20,20, 7, 5] +
  31X[20,20, 8, 4] + 38X[20,20, 9, 3] + 42X[20,20,10, 2] +
  43X[20,20,11, 1] + 41X[20,20,12, 0] +  3X[21,11,10,10] +
   6X[21,11,11, 9] + 15X[21,12,10, 9] + 24X[21,12,11, 8] +
  21X[21,12,12, 7] + 15X[21,13, 9, 9] + 42X[21,13,10, 8] +
  60X[21,13,11, 7] + 63X[21,13,12, 6] + 45X[21,13,13, 5] +
  40X[21,14, 9, 8] + 74X[21,14,10, 7] + 96X[21,14,11, 6] +
 100X[21,14,12, 5] + 80X[21,14,13, 4] + 36X[21,14,14, 3] +
  24X[21,15, 8, 8] + 69X[21,15, 9, 7] +105X[21,15,10, 6] +
 126X[21,15,11, 5] +126X[21,15,12, 4] +105X[21,15,13, 3] +
  63X[21,15,14, 2] + 28X[21,15,15, 1] + 51X[21,16, 8, 7] +
  96X[21,16, 9, 6] +129X[21,16,10, 5] +144X[21,16,11, 4] +
 141X[21,16,12, 3] +120X[21,16,13, 2] + 81X[21,16,14, 1] +
  48X[21,16,15, 0] + 26X[21,17, 7, 7] + 75X[21,17, 8, 6] +
 115X[21,17, 9, 5] +140X[21,17,10, 4] +150X[21,17,11, 3] +
 145X[21,17,12, 2] +125X[21,17,13, 1] + 90X[21,17,14, 0] +
  48X[21,18, 7, 6] + 90X[21,18, 8, 5] +120X[21,18, 9, 4] +
 138X[21,18,10, 3] +144X[21,18,11, 2] +138X[21,18,12, 1] +
 120X[21,18,13, 0] + 21X[21,19, 6, 6] + 60X[21,19, 7, 5] +
  90X[21,19, 8, 4] +111X[21,19, 9, 3] +123X[21,19,10, 2] +
 126X[21,19,11, 1] +120X[21,19,12, 0] + 31X[21,20, 6, 5] +
  56X[21,20, 7, 4] + 75X[21,20, 8, 3] + 88X[21,20, 9, 2] +
  95X[21,20,10, 1] + 96X[21,20,11, 0] +  9X[21,21, 5, 5] +
...
  46X[25,21, 3, 3] +135X[25,21, 4, 2] +215X[25,21, 5, 1] +
 280X[25,21, 6, 0] + 80X[25,22, 3, 2] +154X[25,22, 4, 1] +
 216X[25,22, 5, 0] + 33X[25,23, 2, 2] + 96X[25,23, 3, 1] +
 150X[25,23, 4, 0] + 47X[25,24, 2, 1] + 88X[25,24, 3, 0] +
  13X[25,25, 1, 1] + 36X[25,25, 2, 0] +  3X[26, 9, 9, 8] +
   6X[26,10, 8, 8] + 15X[26,10, 9, 7] + 15X[26,10,10, 6] +
  24X[26,11, 8, 7] + 42X[26,11, 9, 6] + 48X[26,11,10, 5] +
  36X[26,11,11, 4] + 21X[26,12, 7, 7] + 60X[26,12, 8, 6] +
  90X[26,12, 9, 5] +105X[26,12,10, 4] + 99X[26,12,11, 3] +
  66X[26,12,12, 2] + 63X[26,13, 7, 6] +120X[26,13, 8, 5] +
 165X[26,13, 9, 4] +192X[26,13,10, 3] +195X[26,13,11, 2] +
 168X[26,13,12, 1] +105X[26,13,13, 0] + 41X[26,14, 6, 6] +
 120X[26,14, 7, 5] +190X[26,14, 8, 4] +245X[26,14, 9, 3] +
 279X[26,14,10, 2] +286X[26,14,11, 1] +260X[26,14,12, 0] +
  96X[26,15, 6, 5] +186X[26,15, 7, 4] +264X[26,15, 8, 3] +
 324X[26,15, 9, 2] +360X[26,15,10, 1] +366X[26,15,11, 0] +
  54X[26,16, 5, 5] +159X[26,16, 6, 4] +255X[26,16, 7, 3] +
 336X[26,16, 8, 2] +396X[26,16, 9, 1] +429X[26,16,10, 0] +
 115X[26,17, 5, 4] +224X[26,17, 6, 3] +321X[26,17, 7, 2] +
 400X[26,17, 8, 1] +455X[26,17, 9, 0] + 60X[26,18, 4, 4] +
 177X[26,18, 5, 3] +285X[26,18, 6, 2] +378X[26,18, 7, 1] +
 450X[26,18, 8, 0] +120X[26,19, 4, 3] +234X[26,19, 5, 2] +
 336X[26,19, 6, 1] +420X[26,19, 7, 0] + 59X[26,20, 3, 3] +
 174X[26,20, 4, 2] +280X[26,20, 5, 1] +371X[26,20, 6, 0] +
 111X[26,21, 3, 2] +216X[26,21, 4, 1] +309X[26,21, 5, 0] +
  51X[26,22, 2, 2] +150X[26,22, 3, 1] +240X[26,22, 4, 0] +
  88X[26,23, 2, 1] +170X[26,23, 3, 0] + 36X[26,24, 1, 1] +
 105X[26,24, 2, 0] + 51X[26,25, 1, 0] + 14X[26,26, 0, 0] +
   3X[27, 9, 8, 8] +  6X[27, 9, 9, 7] + 15X[27,10, 8, 7] +
  24X[27,10, 9, 6] + 21X[27,10,10, 5] + 15X[27,11, 7, 7] +
  42X[27,11, 8, 6] + 60X[27,11, 9, 5] + 63X[27,11,10, 4] +
  45X[27,11,11, 3] + 48X[27,12, 7, 6] + 90X[27,12, 8, 5] +
 120X[27,12, 9, 4] +132X[27,12,10, 3] +120X[27,12,11, 2] +
  78X[27,12,12, 1] + 36X[27,13, 6, 6] +105X[27,13, 7, 5] +
 165X[27,13, 8, 4] +210X[27,13, 9, 3] +234X[27,13,10, 2] +
 231X[27,13,11, 1] +195X[27,13,12, 0] + 91X[27,14, 6, 5] +
 176X[27,14, 7, 4] +249X[27,14, 8, 3] +304X[27,14, 9, 2] +
 335X[27,14,10, 1] +336X[27,14,11, 0] + 54X[27,15, 5, 5] +
 159X[27,15, 6, 4] +255X[27,15, 7, 3] +336X[27,15, 8, 2] +
 396X[27,15, 9, 1] +429X[27,15,10, 0] +120X[27,16, 5, 4] +
 234X[27,16, 6, 3] +336X[27,16, 7, 2] +420X[27,16, 8, 1] +
 480X[27,16, 9, 0] + 65X[27,17, 4, 4] +192X[27,17, 5, 3] +
 310X[27,17, 6, 2] +413X[27,17, 7, 1] +495X[27,17, 8, 0] +
 135X[27,18, 4, 3] +264X[27,18, 5, 2] +381X[27,18, 6, 1] +
 480X[27,18, 7, 0] + 69X[27,19, 3, 3] +204X[27,19, 4, 2] +
 330X[27,19, 5, 1] +441X[27,19, 6, 0] +136X[27,20, 3, 2] +
 266X[27,20, 4, 1] +384X[27,20, 5, 0] + 66X[27,21, 2, 2] +
 195X[27,21, 3, 1] +315X[27,21, 4, 0] +123X[27,22, 2, 1] +
 240X[27,22, 3, 0] + 56X[27,23, 1, 1] +165X[27,23, 2, 0] +
  96X[27,24, 1, 0] + 39X[27,25, 0, 0] +  1X[28, 8, 8, 8] +
   8X[28, 9, 8, 7] + 10X[28, 9, 9, 6] + 10X[28,10, 7, 7] +
  27X[28,10, 8, 6] + 35X[28,10, 9, 5] + 28X[28,10,10, 4] +
  35X[28,11, 7, 6] + 64X[28,11, 8, 5] + 81X[28,11, 9, 4] +
  80X[28,11,10, 3] + 55X[28,11,11, 2] + 28X[28,12, 6, 6] +
  81X[28,12, 7, 5] +125X[28,12, 8, 4] +154X[28,12, 9, 3] +
 162X[28,12,10, 2] +143X[28,12,11, 1] + 91X[28,12,12, 0] +
  80X[28,13, 6, 5] +154X[28,13, 7, 4] +216X[28,13, 8, 3] +
 260X[28,13, 9, 2] +280X[28,13,10, 1] +270X[28,13,11, 0] +
  51X[28,14, 5, 5] +150X[28,14, 6, 4] +240X[28,14, 7, 3] +
 315X[28,14, 8, 2] +369X[28,14, 9, 1] +396X[28,14,10, 0] +
 119X[28,15, 5, 4] +232X[28,15, 6, 3] +333X[28,15, 7, 2] +
 416X[28,15, 8, 1] +475X[28,15, 9, 0] + 67X[28,16, 4, 4] +
 198X[28,16, 5, 3] +320X[28,16, 6, 2] +427X[28,16, 7, 1] +
 513X[28,16, 8, 0] +144X[28,17, 4, 3] +282X[28,17, 5, 2] +
 408X[28,17, 6, 1] +516X[28,17, 7, 0] + 76X[28,18, 3, 3] +
 225X[28,18, 4, 2] +365X[28,18, 5, 1] +490X[28,18, 6, 0] +
 155X[28,19, 3, 2] +304X[28,19, 4, 1] +441X[28,19, 5, 0] +
  78X[28,20, 2, 2] +231X[28,20, 3, 1] +375X[28,20, 4, 0] +
 152X[28,21, 2, 1] +298X[28,21, 3, 0] + 73X[28,22, 1, 1] +
 216X[28,22, 2, 0] +135X[28,23, 1, 0] + 61X[28,24, 0, 0] +
   3X[29, 8, 8, 7] +  6X[29, 9, 7, 7] + 15X[29, 9, 8, 6] +
  15X[29, 9, 9, 5] + 24X[29,10, 7, 6] + 42X[29,10, 8, 5] +
  48X[29,10, 9, 4] + 36X[29,10,10, 3] + 21X[29,11, 6, 6] +
  60X[29,11, 7, 5] + 90X[29,11, 8, 4] +105X[29,11, 9, 3] +
  99X[29,11,10, 2] + 66X[29,11,11, 1] + 63X[29,12, 6, 5] +
 120X[29,12, 7, 4] +165X[29,12, 8, 3] +192X[29,12, 9, 2] +
 195X[29,12,10, 1] +168X[29,12,11, 0] + 45X[29,13, 5, 5] +
 132X[29,13, 6, 4] +210X[29,13, 7, 3] +273X[29,13, 8, 2] +
 315X[29,13, 9, 1] +330X[29,13,10, 0] +112X[29,14, 5, 4] +
 218X[29,14, 6, 3] +312X[29,14, 7, 2] +388X[29,14, 8, 1] +
 440X[29,14, 9, 0] + 66X[29,15, 4, 4] +195X[29,15, 5, 3] +
 315X[29,15, 6, 2] +420X[29,15, 7, 1] +504X[29,15, 8, 0] +
 147X[29,16, 4, 3] +288X[29,16, 5, 2] +417X[29,16, 6, 1] +
 528X[29,16, 7, 0] + 80X[29,17, 3, 3] +237X[29,17, 4, 2] +
 385X[29,17, 5, 1] +518X[29,17, 6, 0] +168X[29,18, 3, 2] +
 330X[29,18, 4, 1] +480X[29,18, 5, 0] + 87X[29,19, 2, 2] +
 258X[29,19, 3, 1] +420X[29,19, 4, 0] +175X[29,20, 2, 1] +
 344X[29,20, 3, 0] + 87X[29,21, 1, 1] +258X[29,21, 2, 0] +
 168X[29,22, 1, 0] + 80X[29,23, 0, 0] +  3X[30, 8, 7, 7] +
   6X[30, 8, 8, 6] + 15X[30, 9, 7, 6] + 24X[30, 9, 8, 5] +
  21X[30, 9, 9, 4] + 15X[30,10, 6, 6] + 42X[30,10, 7, 5] +
  60X[30,10, 8, 4] + 63X[30,10, 9, 3] + 45X[30,10,10, 2] +
  48X[30,11, 6, 5] + 90X[30,11, 7, 4] +120X[30,11, 8, 3] +
 132X[30,11, 9, 2] +120X[30,11,10, 1] + 78X[30,11,11, 0] +
  36X[30,12, 5, 5] +105X[30,12, 6, 4] +165X[30,12, 7, 3] +
 210X[30,12, 8, 2] +234X[30,12, 9, 1] +231X[30,12,10, 0] +
  99X[30,13, 5, 4] +192X[30,13, 6, 3] +273X[30,13, 7, 2] +
 336X[30,13, 8, 1] +375X[30,13, 9, 0] + 62X[30,14, 4, 4] +
 183X[30,14, 5, 3] +295X[30,14, 6, 2] +392X[30,14, 7, 1] +
 468X[30,14, 8, 0] +144X[30,15, 4, 3] +282X[30,15, 5, 2] +
 408X[30,15, 6, 1] +516X[30,15, 7, 0] + 81X[30,16, 3, 3] +
 240X[30,16, 4, 2] +390X[30,16, 5, 1] +525X[30,16, 6, 0] +
 175X[30,17, 3, 2] +344X[30,17, 4, 1] +501X[30,17, 5, 0] +
  93X[30,18, 2, 2] +276X[30,18, 3, 1] +450X[30,18, 4, 0] +
 192X[30,19, 2, 1] +378X[30,19, 3, 0] + 98X[30,20, 1, 1] +
 291X[30,20, 2, 0] +195X[30,21, 1, 0] + 96X[30,22, 0, 0] +
   1X[31, 7, 7, 7] +  8X[31, 8, 7, 6] + 10X[31, 8, 8, 5] +
  10X[31, 9, 6, 6] + 27X[31, 9, 7, 5] + 35X[31, 9, 8, 4] +
  28X[31, 9, 9, 3] + 35X[31,10, 6, 5] + 64X[31,10, 7, 4] +
  81X[31,10, 8, 3] + 80X[31,10, 9, 2] + 55X[31,10,10, 1] +
  28X[31,11, 5, 5] + 81X[31,11, 6, 4] +125X[31,11, 7, 3] +
 154X[31,11, 8, 2] +162X[31,11, 9, 1] +143X[31,11,10, 0] +
  80X[31,12, 5, 4] +154X[31,12, 6, 3] +216X[31,12, 7, 2] +
 260X[31,12, 8, 1] +280X[31,12, 9, 0] + 55X[31,13, 4, 4] +
 162X[31,13, 5, 3] +260X[31,13, 6, 2] +343X[31,13, 7, 1] +
 405X[31,13, 8, 0] +135X[31,14, 4, 3] +264X[31,14, 5, 2] +
 381X[31,14, 6, 1] +480X[31,14, 7, 0] + 79X[31,15, 3, 3] +
 234X[31,15, 4, 2] +380X[31,15, 5, 1] +511X[31,15, 6, 0] +
 176X[31,16, 3, 2] +346X[31,16, 4, 1] +504X[31,16, 5, 0] +
  96X[31,17, 2, 2] +285X[31,17, 3, 1] +465X[31,17, 4, 0] +
 203X[31,18, 2, 1] +400X[31,18, 3, 0] +106X[31,19, 1, 1] +
 315X[31,19, 2, 0] +216X[31,20, 1, 0] +109X[31,21, 0, 0] +
   3X[32, 7, 7, 6] +  6X[32, 8, 6, 6] + 15X[32, 8, 7, 5] +
  15X[32, 8, 8, 4] + 24X[32, 9, 6, 5] + 42X[32, 9, 7, 4] +
  48X[32, 9, 8, 3] + 36X[32, 9, 9, 2] + 21X[32,10, 5, 5] +
  60X[32,10, 6, 4] + 90X[32,10, 7, 3] +105X[32,10, 8, 2] +
  99X[32,10, 9, 1] + 66X[32,10,10, 0] + 63X[32,11, 5, 4] +
 120X[32,11, 6, 3] +165X[32,11, 7, 2] +192X[32,11, 8, 1] +
 195X[32,11, 9, 0] + 45X[32,12, 4, 4] +132X[32,12, 5, 3] +
 210X[32,12, 6, 2] +273X[32,12, 7, 1] +315X[32,12, 8, 0] +
 120X[32,13, 4, 3] +234X[32,13, 5, 2] +336X[32,13, 6, 1] +
 420X[32,13, 7, 0] + 74X[32,14, 3, 3] +219X[32,14, 4, 2] +
 355X[32,14, 5, 1] +476X[32,14, 6, 0] +171X[32,15, 3, 2] +
 336X[32,15, 4, 1] +489X[32,15, 5, 0] + 96X[32,16, 2, 2] +
 285X[32,16, 3, 1] +465X[32,16, 4, 0] +208X[32,17, 2, 1] +
 410X[32,17, 3, 0] +111X[32,18, 1, 1] +330X[32,18, 2, 0] +
 231X[32,19, 1, 0] +119X[32,20, 0, 0] +  3X[33, 7, 6, 6] +
   6X[33, 7, 7, 5] + 15X[33, 8, 6, 5] + 24X[33, 8, 7, 4] +
  21X[33, 8, 8, 3] + 15X[33, 9, 5, 5] + 42X[33, 9, 6, 4] +
  60X[33, 9, 7, 3] + 63X[33, 9, 8, 2] + 45X[33, 9, 9, 1] +
  48X[33,10, 5, 4] + 90X[33,10, 6, 3] +120X[33,10, 7, 2] +
 132X[33,10, 8, 1] +120X[33,10, 9, 0] + 36X[33,11, 4, 4] +
 105X[33,11, 5, 3] +165X[33,11, 6, 2] +210X[33,11, 7, 1] +
 234X[33,11, 8, 0] + 99X[33,12, 4, 3] +192X[33,12, 5, 2] +
 273X[33,12, 6, 1] +336X[33,12, 7, 0] + 66X[33,13, 3, 3] +
 195X[33,13, 4, 2] +315X[33,13, 5, 1] +420X[33,13, 6, 0] +
 160X[33,14, 3, 2] +314X[33,14, 4, 1] +456X[33,14, 5, 0] +
  93X[33,15, 2, 2] +276X[33,15, 3, 1] +450X[33,15, 4, 0] +
 207X[33,16, 2, 1] +408X[33,16, 3, 0] +113X[33,17, 1, 1] +
 336X[33,17, 2, 0] +240X[33,18, 1, 0] +126X[33,19, 0, 0] +
   1X[34, 6, 6, 6] +  8X[34, 7, 6, 5] + 10X[34, 7, 7, 4] +
  10X[34, 8, 5, 5] + 27X[34, 8, 6, 4] + 35X[34, 8, 7, 3] +
  28X[34, 8, 8, 2] + 35X[34, 9, 5, 4] + 64X[34, 9, 6, 3] +
  81X[34, 9, 7, 2] + 80X[34, 9, 8, 1] + 55X[34, 9, 9, 0] +
  28X[34,10, 4, 4] + 81X[34,10, 5, 3] +125X[34,10, 6, 2] +
 154X[34,10, 7, 1] +162X[34,10, 8, 0] + 80X[34,11, 4, 3] +
 154X[34,11, 5, 2] +216X[34,11, 6, 1] +260X[34,11, 7, 0] +
  55X[34,12, 3, 3] +162X[34,12, 4, 2] +260X[34,12, 5, 1] +
 343X[34,12, 6, 0] +143X[34,13, 3, 2] +280X[34,13, 4, 1] +
 405X[34,13, 5, 0] + 87X[34,14, 2, 2] +258X[34,14, 3, 1] +
 420X[34,14, 4, 0] +200X[34,15, 2, 1] +394X[34,15, 3, 0] +
 112X[34,16, 1, 1] +333X[34,16, 2, 0] +243X[34,17, 1, 0] +
 130X[34,18, 0, 0] +  3X[35, 6, 6, 5] +  6X[35, 7, 5, 5] +
  15X[35, 7, 6, 4] + 15X[35, 7, 7, 3] + 24X[35, 8, 5, 4] +
  42X[35, 8, 6, 3] + 48X[35, 8, 7, 2] + 36X[35, 8, 8, 1] +
  21X[35, 9, 4, 4] + 60X[35, 9, 5, 3] + 90X[35, 9, 6, 2] +
 105X[35, 9, 7, 1] + 99X[35, 9, 8, 0] + 63X[35,10, 4, 3] +
 120X[35,10, 5, 2] +165X[35,10, 6, 1] +192X[35,10, 7, 0] +
  45X[35,11, 3, 3] +132X[35,11, 4, 2] +210X[35,11, 5, 1] +
 273X[35,11, 6, 0] +120X[35,12, 3, 2] +234X[35,12, 4, 1] +
 336X[35,12, 5, 0] + 78X[35,13, 2, 2] +231X[35,13, 3, 1] +
 375X[35,13, 4, 0] +187X[35,14, 2, 1] +368X[35,14, 3, 0] +
 108X[35,15, 1, 1] +321X[35,15, 2, 0] +240X[35,16, 1, 0] +
 131X[35,17, 0, 0] +  3X[36, 6, 5, 5] +  6X[36, 6, 6, 4] +
  15X[36, 7, 5, 4] + 24X[36, 7, 6, 3] + 21X[36, 7, 7, 2] +
  15X[36, 8, 4, 4] + 42X[36, 8, 5, 3] + 60X[36, 8, 6, 2] +
  63X[36, 8, 7, 1] + 45X[36, 8, 8, 0] + 48X[36, 9, 4, 3] +
  90X[36, 9, 5, 2] +120X[36, 9, 6, 1] +132X[36, 9, 7, 0] +
  36X[36,10, 3, 3] +105X[36,10, 4, 2] +165X[36,10, 5, 1] +
 210X[36,10, 6, 0] + 99X[36,11, 3, 2] +192X[36,11, 4, 1] +
 273X[36,11, 5, 0] + 66X[36,12, 2, 2] +195X[36,12, 3, 1] +
 315X[36,12, 4, 0] +168X[36,13, 2, 1] +330X[36,13, 3, 0] +
 101X[36,14, 1, 1] +300X[36,14, 2, 0] +231X[36,15, 1, 0] +
 129X[36,16, 0, 0] +  1X[37, 5, 5, 5] +  8X[37, 6, 5, 4] +
  10X[37, 6, 6, 3] + 10X[37, 7, 4, 4] + 27X[37, 7, 5, 3] +
  35X[37, 7, 6, 2] + 28X[37, 7, 7, 1] + 35X[37, 8, 4, 3] +
  64X[37, 8, 5, 2] + 81X[37, 8, 6, 1] + 80X[37, 8, 7, 0] +
  28X[37, 9, 3, 3] + 81X[37, 9, 4, 2] +125X[37, 9, 5, 1] +
 154X[37, 9, 6, 0] + 80X[37,10, 3, 2] +154X[37,10, 4, 1] +
 216X[37,10, 5, 0] + 55X[37,11, 2, 2] +162X[37,11, 3, 1] +
 260X[37,11, 4, 0] +143X[37,12, 2, 1] +280X[37,12, 3, 0] +
  91X[37,13, 1, 1] +270X[37,13, 2, 0] +216X[37,14, 1, 0] +
 124X[37,15, 0, 0] +  3X[38, 5, 5, 4] +  6X[38, 6, 4, 4] +
  15X[38, 6, 5, 3] + 15X[38, 6, 6, 2] + 24X[38, 7, 4, 3] +
  42X[38, 7, 5, 2] + 48X[38, 7, 6, 1] + 36X[38, 7, 7, 0] +
  21X[38, 8, 3, 3] + 60X[38, 8, 4, 2] + 90X[38, 8, 5, 1] +
 105X[38, 8, 6, 0] + 63X[38, 9, 3, 2] +120X[38, 9, 4, 1] +
 165X[38, 9, 5, 0] + 45X[38,10, 2, 2] +132X[38,10, 3, 1] +
 210X[38,10, 4, 0] +120X[38,11, 2, 1] +234X[38,11, 3, 0] +
  78X[38,12, 1, 1] +231X[38,12, 2, 0] +195X[38,13, 1, 0] +
 116X[38,14, 0, 0] +  3X[39, 5, 4, 4] +  6X[39, 5, 5, 3] +
  15X[39, 6, 4, 3] + 24X[39, 6, 5, 2] + 21X[39, 6, 6, 1] +
  15X[39, 7, 3, 3] + 42X[39, 7, 4, 2] + 60X[39, 7, 5, 1] +
  63X[39, 7, 6, 0] + 48X[39, 8, 3, 2] + 90X[39, 8, 4, 1] +
 120X[39, 8, 5, 0] + 36X[39, 9, 2, 2] +105X[39, 9, 3, 1] +
 165X[39, 9, 4, 0] + 99X[39,10, 2, 1] +192X[39,10, 3, 0] +
  66X[39,11, 1, 1] +195X[39,11, 2, 0] +168X[39,12, 1, 0] +
 105X[39,13, 0, 0] +  1X[40, 4, 4, 4] +  8X[40, 5, 4, 3] +
  10X[40, 5, 5, 2] + 10X[40, 6, 3, 3] + 27X[40, 6, 4, 2] +
  35X[40, 6, 5, 1] + 28X[40, 6, 6, 0] + 35X[40, 7, 3, 2] +
  64X[40, 7, 4, 1] + 81X[40, 7, 5, 0] + 28X[40, 8, 2, 2] +
  81X[40, 8, 3, 1] +125X[40, 8, 4, 0] + 80X[40, 9, 2, 1] +
 154X[40, 9, 3, 0] + 55X[40,10, 1, 1] +162X[40,10, 2, 0] +
 143X[40,11, 1, 0] + 91X[40,12, 0, 0] +  3X[41, 4, 4, 3] +
   6X[41, 5, 3, 3] + 15X[41, 5, 4, 2] + 15X[41, 5, 5, 1] +
  24X[41, 6, 3, 2] + 42X[41, 6, 4, 1] + 48X[41, 6, 5, 0] +
  21X[41, 7, 2, 2] + 60X[41, 7, 3, 1] + 90X[41, 7, 4, 0] +
  63X[41, 8, 2, 1] +120X[41, 8, 3, 0] + 45X[41, 9, 1, 1] +
 132X[41, 9, 2, 0] +120X[41,10, 1, 0] + 78X[41,11, 0, 0] +
   3X[42, 4, 3, 3] +  6X[42, 4, 4, 2] + 15X[42, 5, 3, 2] +
  24X[42, 5, 4, 1] + 21X[42, 5, 5, 0] + 15X[42, 6, 2, 2] +
  42X[42, 6, 3, 1] + 60X[42, 6, 4, 0] + 48X[42, 7, 2, 1] +
  90X[42, 7, 3, 0] + 36X[42, 8, 1, 1] +105X[42, 8, 2, 0] +
  99X[42, 9, 1, 0] + 66X[42,10, 0, 0] +  1X[43, 3, 3, 3] +
   8X[43, 4, 3, 2] + 10X[43, 4, 4, 1] + 10X[43, 5, 2, 2] +
  27X[43, 5, 3, 1] + 35X[43, 5, 4, 0] + 35X[43, 6, 2, 1] +
  64X[43, 6, 3, 0] + 28X[43, 7, 1, 1] + 81X[43, 7, 2, 0] +
  80X[43, 8, 1, 0] + 55X[43, 9, 0, 0] +  3X[44, 3, 3, 2] +
   6X[44, 4, 2, 2] + 15X[44, 4, 3, 1] + 15X[44, 4, 4, 0] +
  24X[44, 5, 2, 1] + 42X[44, 5, 3, 0] + 21X[44, 6, 1, 1] +
  60X[44, 6, 2, 0] + 63X[44, 7, 1, 0] + 45X[44, 8, 0, 0] +
   3X[45, 3, 2, 2] +  6X[45, 3, 3, 1] + 15X[45, 4, 2, 1] +
  24X[45, 4, 3, 0] + 15X[45, 5, 1, 1] + 42X[45, 5, 2, 0] +
  48X[45, 6, 1, 0] + 36X[45, 7, 0, 0] +  1X[46, 2, 2, 2] +
   8X[46, 3, 2, 1] + 10X[46, 3, 3, 0] + 10X[46, 4, 1, 1] +
  27X[46, 4, 2, 0] + 35X[46, 5, 1, 0] + 28X[46, 6, 0, 0] +
   3X[47, 2, 2, 1] +  6X[47, 3, 1, 1] + 15X[47, 3, 2, 0] +
  24X[47, 4, 1, 0] + 21X[47, 5, 0, 0] +  3X[48, 2, 1, 1] +
   6X[48, 2, 2, 0] + 15X[48, 3, 1, 0] + 15X[48, 4, 0, 0] +
   1X[49, 1, 1, 1] +  8X[49, 2, 1, 0] + 10X[49, 3, 0, 0] +
   3X[50, 1, 1, 0] +  6X[50, 2, 0, 0] +  3X[51, 1, 0, 0] +
   1X[52, 0, 0, 0]
```

And the distribution of tableaux of weight $(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)$ (just a small part because of the $30\,000$ character limit in MSE answers):

```
     8918879464X[13,13,13,13] +  115264660368X[14,13,13,12] +
   142724371790X[14,14,12,12] +  293987005455X[14,14,13,11] +
   191374221610X[14,14,14,10] +  301405968864X[15,13,12,12] +
   515082182472X[15,13,13,11] +  996620219595X[15,14,12,11] +
  1268164427244X[15,14,13,10] +  740149965126X[15,14,14, 9] +
   515347564095X[15,15,11,11] + 1246756723212X[15,15,12,10] +
  1316958103890X[15,15,13, 9] +  854132381388X[15,15,14, 8] +
...
          12012X[47, 4, 1, 0] +          4355X[47, 5, 0, 0] +
           2145X[48, 2, 1, 1] +          1716X[48, 2, 2, 0] +
           3003X[48, 3, 1, 0] +          1365X[48, 4, 0, 0] +
            220X[49, 1, 1, 1] +           572X[49, 2, 1, 0] +
            364X[49, 3, 0, 0] +            66X[50, 1, 1, 0] +
             78X[50, 2, 0, 0] +            12X[51, 1, 0, 0] +
              1X[52, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

No real answer, but a reformulation (too wide for a comment):

Compute the number of $13\times4$-matrices $A=\left(a_{ij}\right)$
having nonnegative integers as entries with $\sum_{j=1}^{4}a_{ij}=4$
for each $i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{13}a_{ij}=13$ for each $j$.

When the players are indistinghuisable then the matrices must be split up in matrices with:

- $4$ distinct columns.
- exactly $3$ distinct columns.
- exactly $2$ distinct columns and no column differs from all other columns.
- exactly $2$ distinct columns and exactly one column differs from all other columns.
- all columns are the same.

To repair double counting the number of matrices in these separate cases must - before addition takes place - be divided respectively by:

- $4!=24$
- $\binom42\times2!=12$
- $\binom42=6$
- $\binom41=4$
- $1$

Quite a job, I think. My compliments allready for the person who offers you a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can see your cards as a list of $4 \cdot 13 = 52$ numbers:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

The fact that every player gets 13 cards is implicitly represented here. The first 13 cards belong to player 1, the next 13 to player 2, ...

Then you have to get all possible orderings of that list. The first card can be at $52$ positions, the second card at $51$ positions, ... resulting in $52! \approx 8.1 \cdot 10^{67}$ possible orderings. This is certainly an upper bound.

Now you can also see that you can change the ordering of all 0s without getting a different result. So we have $\binom{52}{4}$ ways to get the positions for 0s, then $\binom{52-4}{4}$ ways to get the position for 1s,... resulting in

$$\prod_{i=1}^{13} \binom{4\cdot i}{4} \approx 9.2 \cdot 10^{49}$$

possible orderings resulting in a tighter **upper bound**.

But there are less orderings, because

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

and

```
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

mean the same "distribution" of cards to players. In how many ways can one player arrange his cards?

At most, in $13!$ ways for each player. So

$$\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{13} \binom{4\cdot i}{4}}{(13!)^4} = 6.1 \cdot 10^{10}$$

is a **lower bound**.

I am not sure if it makes sense to continue this approach, but at least I could give you a lower and an upper bound.

Comment: I think in the last equation it should be $(13!)^4$ instead of $4\times 13!$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @is7s Yes, thank you.

Comment: It's a nice approach. I've reached similar results using another approach. But the problem is that the numbers don't make sense when trying them out with smaller examples. For example, 6 cards, 3 classes (two 1's, two 2's and two 3's) to be distributed among 2 players. The result is 2.5 which doesn't really make sense to me.